# Creating a Tensorflow Model Based on Hough Lines

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, tensorflow, computer-vision

So I have a project of creating an autonomous rc car. In order to do virtual training, I have set up a simulator to collect picture data, along with a steering angle. I then use an OpenCV program, using Hough line Detection, to detect the 3 lines on the road. I want to create a model that when images are inputted the output will be a steering angle. Using TensorFlow, I trained a CNN with these images and the result was extremely poor.

What kind of model should I use ?

How should I approach training such images?

[image: Original Simulator Image] and
[image: Hough Lines]

I can also train the data using the actual data for each line which looks like this for one line detected:

> [[[0.0, 63.0, 54.0, 31.0, -0.5925925925925926]]]

And this for 2 lines detected:

> [[[0.0, 61.0, 34.0, 32.0, -0.8529411764705882], [41.0, 42.0, 43.0, 77.0, 17.5]]]

The only problem is I don't know how to deal with inputs of variable size. Help?

Comment: I thought you were detecting “the 3 lines on the road”? I can only see two in your Hough Lines image.

Comment: Call me a boring old-fashioned old fogey if you want, but I'm not so sure as you that a neural network is what you need here. I'd have thought there is a geometric model you can create which might well be easier and also much more predictable when it comes across the curve that it hasn't seen before rather than attempting to train a neural network to give you a steering angle. And note I said "you" because there's no way I'm going to let any neural network steer my car when I don't know what its possible input->output relationships are in *every* circumstance it might come across.

Comment: There are 3 possible lines, but sometimes a line is missed and this needs to be accounted for

Comment: So I guess you need two outputs from your solution: a steering angle, and a signal “Human control necessary” that sounds a klaxon and leaves the driver to make the critical decision where to steer?

Answer (score 0):

now is quite late, but I wish this answer could still be useful.

The CNN is a NN with bidimensional input, so is feed with constant length matrices (images for example); however most of their learning capabilities comes from the fact that CNN's are able of learning from correlated data, so it will work better with the non processed image (in fact the convolutional layer perform an adaptive feature extraction).

I think that if you need to use CNN you should focus on labelling your training images in sets of turning right, left and not turning at all for classification of the turning side and letting the steering control to some fuzzy logic based controller for example.

If you wish to do the control with a NN, I'll use a recurrent one for the decision as you'll need to compare the change of the picture's curve through time